# Details for convolution equation

Tags: math, neural-network, convolution, equation

[Convolution operation from http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~langer/558/10-edgecorner.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3o1k.png)

Hello,
In the context of 2D convolution in a neural network, I would like to know what are the parameters u,v and what represents f(u,v) in the following equation : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3o1k.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u,v` are parameters for summation like this:

```
 for u = -Inf to Inf:   //in practice limits are real values
    for v = -Inf to Inf:
       Result[x][y] += I[x - u][y - v] * f[u][v]
```

and `f(u,v)` is the kernel of convolution. I suppose these details should be explained in every learning text about convolution (yes, not easy subject)